# How do I deep filter array and keep array tree structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, filter, lodash

I need to remove items from nested arrays. I successfully have done this, however I need to keep the complete structure of the tree. The current code outputs the `things` object and has the element removed where `name` equals `'child thing 1'`, however my result misses a lot of other data from the original tree.

I am using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) and [deepdash](https://deepdash.io/) as I will be working with objects with many children.

```js
deepdash(_);

let things = {
  type: 'app',
  info: [],
  things: [{
    name: 'something',
    good: false,
  }, {
    name: 'another thing',
    good: true,
    children: [{
      name: 'child thing 1',
      good: false,
    }, {
      name: 'child thing 2',
      good: true,
    }, {
      name: 'child thing 3',
      good: false,
    }],
  }, {
    name: 'something else',
    good: true,
    subItem: {
      name: 'sub-item',
      good: false,
    },
    subItem2: {
      name: 'sub-item-2',
      good: true,
    },
  }],
};

let filtrate = _.filterDeep(things, (value, key, parent) => {
  if (key == 'name' && parent.name !== 'child thing 1') return true;
});
console.log({ filtrate });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/deepdash/browser/deepdash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: plz put expected output

Comment: [according to the documentation](https://deepdash.io/#finddeep) the OP might need to pass and change some additional `options`. ... btw the return statement might be rewritten into something more direct as ... `return (key === 'name' && value !== 'child thing 1')` ... no need for an `if` clause or the `parent` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear from your question what you're expected result is, as pointed out by @grodzi in the comments. However, it seems like you're just looking for a way to quickly delete sub-structures in an object while maintaining its overall integrity. Lodash provides some nifty functions that simplifies tasks like these.

Two that would help with the task at hand are [`get`](https://lodash.com/docs/#get) and [`omit`](https://lodash.com/docs/#omit)

```js
const pathsToRemove = ['things.1.children.0']; // use object dot notation (.) even for array elements 

const restructure = (object, pathsToRemove) => pathsToRemove.reduce((acc, path) => {

    const parentPath = path.split('.').slice(0,-1).join('.');
    const [targetPath] = path.split('.').slice(-1);

    let parent = _.get(acc, parentPath);

    if (parent.constructor === Array) {
        // this block is to prevent empty array items
        parent.splice(+targetPath, 1);

        return acc;
    }

    return _.omit(acc, path);

}, object);

console.log(JSON.stringify(
    restructure(things, pathsToRemove),
    null,
    4
));
```

I think something like this would get the job done. Make sure to check this yourself though, with tests preferably if this is at all likely to be deployed.